# A question about the question tag of "ought to"

Tags: grammar

When we say : we  ought not to smoke in the class, ought we ?

Is this sentence correct or should it be "don't we?" instead of "ought we?"  or "do we?"  ?
Because this is so confusing. please help!

Comment: "We aren't ought to smoke"?  Really?  Maybe better for ell.stackexchange.com

Comment: Edited* sorry for that. xD

Comment: 'Ought we' is fine, if a bit unusual.  Most people would likely prefer to say "We shouldn't smoke... (..., should we?)"

Comment: *One ought not **to** smoke* sounds almost as strange with that extra *to* in there after the modal as *One should not **to** smoke* would sound. You really oughtn’t smoke no matter its tag-question. :) SEE ALSO [1](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/373663/2085), [2](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/103658), [3](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/197946/2085), [4](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/46458/2085).

Comment: "Ought" is an auxiliary verb in a negative clause, so the tag should contain the same verb in a positive clause: "We ought not to smoke in the class, ought we?"

Comment: Except that that's not what native speakers say. _Ought_ is not used in tag questions. If it's used in the main clause, its tag is _should_.  _We ought to get this one, shouldn't we?_ _Ought not to_ is rare enough already; a tag structure for it is even rarer. _We ought not to smoke, right?_ is about as far as one can go.